# How do I setup Apache to return a 204 code?

Tags: apache

How do I setup Apache to return a 204(no-content) instead of a 404 code for a certain URL?

Comment: This is for an AJAX stile ping, metrics purpose

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Putting together the Redirect documentation with the RedirectMatch documentation, we see that yes, we can send a custom 204 back. Here is a quick example that responds with 204 to any request matching foo with any characters after it.

```
 #RedirectMatch example using mod_alias 
 RedirectMatch 204 foo(.*)$
```

from here
http://www.lowlevelmanager.com/2009/07/returning-apache-204.html

Comment: neat! lowlevelmanager.com is my blog, I'm glad to hear my 204 answer was useful to you.