# configure firebase hosting to return 204 for a specific file request

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I would like to configure firebase hosting to return 204 for a specific file request.

Apache can be easily setup to return  RedirectMatch 204 foo(.*)$
( from [How do I setup Apache to return a 204 code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733643/how-do-i-setup-apache-to-return-a-204-code) )

Can the same be done with firebase hosting configuration in firebase.json ?
If so - how ?

Comment: It looks like your only option is to hook up a Cloud Function to send the custom response. If this is not agreeable, you could always file a feature request with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Cloud Functions solution seems to be an overkill for something that should really be a matter of configuration.  THanks for guidance, will file request for feature with firebase.